# Normal subgroup in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose H is the only subgroup of a group G with order n. Show that H is a normal subgroup of G. I do not know how to start this problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Take an arbitrary $g\in G,$ and consider $$gHg^{-1}:=\{ghg^{-1}\mid h\in H\}.$$ What can you say about this set?

Comment: the order of this set is equal to n

Comment: Great start! What else is worthy of note?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: i kind of post an answer so let me know if i am right or wrong

Comment: There are several things going wrong with your approach. Most significantly: (1) we *never* assumed that $H$ was the only subgroup of $G,$ and (2) not every subset is a subgroup. However, you *should* be able to prove that $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G.$

Answer (score 0):

let |H|= n and H < G. Consider the set $gHg_{1}$= {$ghg_{1}$ | h $in$ H}. The order of $gHg_{1}$=n. So |H| = |$gHg_{1}$|= n. Which means that $gHg_{1}$ < G. which is a contradiction since H is the only subgroup of G.